# how to write nested Initialiser list, eg a QVector of QPairs

Tags: c++, qt, initializer-list, qvector

Warning:

> qvector.h(509): warning C4127: conditional expression is constant (main.cpp)
>    qvector.h(506) : while compiling class template member function
>   'QVector>::QVector(std::initializer_list)'
>   being compiled with  [T=QPair]
>
> see reference to function template instantiation 'QVector>::QVector(std::initializer_list)' being compiled

my code:

```
QVector< QPair< double, float> > container(
        {{40, 0.0f},
         {70, 0.95f},
         {80, 0.7f}}
);
```

It builds fine, I just want the warnings gone (without changing the warning level). What am I doing wrong?

/* edit */

Does no one have any comments on what the warning is? what it exactly means?, whether other people have the warning? I looked up the QT documentation on initializer lists for QVectors and it didn't say much. Does no one have anything to say in general about function template instantiation?

Comment: is the missing semicolon just in your paste?

Comment: haha yes ;) thanks.
 think the compiler would struggle building in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning seems unavoidable and less to do with my initialiser-list, more to do with qvector. 
Any constructor for Qvector  checks

```
  if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex)
```

This is a simple enum value, there are a couple classes with no template, template *, or template in the syntax of the class name declaration listed below. Would love to have that explained to me!

```
template <typename T>
class QTypeInfo { enumbla;}

template<>
class QTypeInfo<void> { enumbla;}

template <typename T>
class QTypeInfo<T*> { enumbla;}
```

So the if looks up the enum value for the appropriate QTypeInfo class, which is a constant as its an enum yay!

Yay unavoidable warnings, more things to suppress!